# How to fix Spring Cloud Data Flow Kubernetes container Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 401

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Have deployed Spring Cloud Data flow on Azure AKS using Helm: ***helm install --name my-release stable/spring-cloud-data-flow***

```
Data Flow Server Implementation
Name: spring-cloud-dataflow-server
Version: 2.0.1.RELEASE
```

But getting Liveness probe and Readiness probe failed 401:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From                               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----                               -------
  Warning  Unhealthy  10m (x52 over 103m)   kubelet, aks-nodepool1-28921497-0  Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 401
  Warning  BackOff    6m8s (x138 over 73m)  kubelet, aks-nodepool1-28921497-0  Back-off restarting failed container
  Warning  Unhealthy  67s (x220 over 104m)  kubelet, aks-nodepool1-28921497-0  Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 401
```

Reading this dococument https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_application_and_server_properties

deployer.appName.kubernetes.probeCredentialsSecret=myprobesecret

But how to Set/Run the deployer properties if using Helm only to deploy Data Flow on AKS cluster ?

Or how to make the release using the default ProbeSecret ? I did not create or modify ProbeSecret when deploying the DataFlow with Helm.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We support a variety of [deployer properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-kubernetes-deployer) that you can override per stream/task deployment in SCDF. The `probeCredentialsSecret` property is one of them and it is specifically designed to supply a secret to gain access to a protected liveness and readiness probes.

Whether or not you used Helm to provision SCDF on K8s, the actual property needs to be supplied at the time of stream/task deployment.

Unless you create a secret and configure it in SCDF, you will not be able to successfully handshake with the secured probes.

Please follow the [ref. guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-kubernetes-probes) that walks through the configuration with an example.